# Autocomplete entity reference - Required to select entity

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax, entities

I'm having problems with a required field that is an entity reference. This is my case:

I have a content type `advertisement` that has an **entity reference** `product`, what is an **autocomplete widget**. The entity reference is a required field (so when it's empty you have to fill something in).

When you start to type in the text field you get a list of suggestions to select from. But you can also type some text and DON'T select a suggestion, the form will submit and the content will be created. I don't want that. I would like to create an error that when you don't select one from the list you receive an error.

What happens when you don't select a suggestion: the advertisement is created but the product is empty!

Is there a way that I can create an error when you don't select one from the list?

Comment: What you've just described is rather strange. The entity reference widget should be able to reference just already existing entities and if non-existent entity is entered it should throw an form error. Is the field really set up as required (i.e. is there a red star next to it?)

Comment: Either way, if I write something nonsensical (e.g. not matching any entity) into the field I get "There are no entities matching "sdfsdfsdf"" If I leave it empty I get "TST_aut field is required." error. So I'd suggest you to make sure you use the last version of entity reference (I believe there was a bug in earlier versions that behaved like this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the Autocomplete widget or are you using the Autocomplete (Tags Style)? I believe tags style allows for an entity to be created like taxonomy term.